# Ruby Link to home#index _path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby and I need help.

on my "app\view\home\index" -> localhost
I got

```
<%= link_to "Blog", posts_path %>
```

that leads me to -> localhost/posts

so far so good.
now here is where the problem stats.

on my "app\view\posts\index" -> localhost/posts
I got

```
<%= link_to "Home" %>
```

That links me to the same page "localhost/posts" but I want it to link to "localhost"

I have tried almost anything but without success.

my routes.rb:

```
BIO::Application.routes.draw do

root :to => 'home#index'

get "home/index"

resources :posts do

resources :comments end
```

Answer (score 24):

add root_path to end of link_to

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Although I did try that before. Is it possible that root :to & get "home:index" outside application.routes.draw would have caused not working it before?

Comment: yes, you have to add all roots inside Application.routes.draw do ... end

Answer (score 3):

Use 'rake routes' to see where you can route your application links. And after name of your link try to use ways from this route list, it is more complex then controller/action/id, but real rails way.

Answer (score 1):

link_to [has several signatures](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

The most common link_to signature uses two parameters: the first one is the text that will appear in the link. The second parameter is the destination URL (i.e. the URL where the user will go after following the link)
If you omit the second parameter, an empty link will be made, and that the reason why you don't change the page.

If you write link_to "Home", root_path as Milan suggested, you'll get a full working link